# Who/what was controlling the killer robot before Wikus got in?

Tags: plot-explanation, district-9

Was it the kid? If it was, it was never clear, unless I missed something.

Answer (score 9):

Yes you missed the scene where Christopher's son activated the killer robot which is actually a battle suit.

As it is clear from the following [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/District_9) plot lines

> Christopher's son activates the mothership and an alien mechanized battle suit which saves Wikus by killing Obesandjo and his men. Wikus takes control of the battle suit and rescues Christopher

Comment: I think that description should read *implied*, since it is not shown. The only clear thing is that the kid turned on the mothership. It is also not shown whether or not the kid actually controls the thing or if it's automatic, so I don't know what a good guess of that is.

Comment: As i remeber kid activeted the suit and mothership both......the battle suit worked automatic till wikus took contol of it

Answer (score 1):

Immediately before Wikus gets in the alien battle mech "suit," there is no indication that anyone is controlling the mech.  So the mech appears to *autonomously* and efficiently defend itself: halting and collecting (with some sort of force field) the hail of bullets fired at it, and then discharging the ball of bullets back at the humans who had fired them.

Given how effective the mech is at defending itself, the question becomes: "Why did the mech become vulnerable to bullets once Wikus was operating it?"  With Wikus at the controls the mech was finally destroyed by accumulated damage from bullets (and one RPG).

Other than for dramatic effect, this plot point seems consistent with the theme that *Wikus is an incompetent boob who can and will screw up anything*.